# Find text position

Tags: browser, text, find, position

Could you please help me !!!! For example, I load some page into opera/Firefox etc., there is a text on the page (which is a link). What I need is to find position of the text on the screen and send mouse click to that position. Is it possible to do? If you can, give an example please!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery. Examples on the site as well, for example: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Answer (score 0):

You won't need to find the position of the link to click it. If using jQuery, the code would look something like:

```
$('a#id-of-link').click();
```